# how to mock resttemplate with ArgumentMatcher?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to mock the restTemplate.exchange when I tried the following code to do that.

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.eq(clientEndpoint.getUrl()),ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(new HttpEntity<>(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.eq(headers))), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Map.class))).thenReturn(rEntity);
```

I got the following error,

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it seems there is no `ArgumentMatchers.eq` then followed by a `new instance`, I changed the code like this

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.eq(clientEndpoint.getUrl()),ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                new HttpEntity<>(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.eq(headers)), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Map.class))).thenReturn(rEntity);
```

and it works to me now